# Grabar Datos de una Jtable en Base de datos

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

Buenas tardes compañeros,

Soy nuevo en este mundo de la programación y tengo un proyecto para entregar un trabajo de estudio y me encontré con el siguiente problema, tengo dos tablas, la primera se llama "SalidaMercancia" y la segunda "DetalleSalidaMercancia"

```
create table salidamercancia
(idsalida int(5) primary key auto_increment not null,
fcontabilizacionsalida date not null,
fdocumentosalida date not null,
comentariossalida varchar(100)
);

create table detalleSalidaMercancia
(idmaterialsalida int(7) not null, 
nombrematerialsalida varchar(50) not null,
codbarrassalida varchar(13) not null,
cantidadsalida int(7) not null,
almacensalida int(3) not null,
preciocomprasalida decimal not null,
totalsalida int(15) not null,
iddetallesalida int(5) not null,
foreign key(iddetallesalida) references salidamercancia(idsalida),
foreign key(idmaterialsalida) references materiales(idmaterial)
);
```

la primera recoge los datos principales de la salida, como es el auto_increment y la fecha en que se realiza el documento, y la segunda donde se ingresan el detalle de la misma, donde lleva todos los artículos descripción y cantidad, si se hace el insert into desde mysql no hay ningún problema. pero cuando se realiza la inserción desde java es cuando se presenta el problema.

La primera parte del código es para mostrar el numero del autoincrement de la tabla "salidamercancia"

```
    public void idsalida(){  //Metodo para el autoincremental.
            Connection con = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = getConection();
                Statement s = con.createStatement();
                
                ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(idsalida) FROM salidamercancia");
                rs.next();
                
                rs.getString("MAX(idsalida)");
    
                if(rs.getString("MAX(idsalida)")==null){
                    txt_salida.setText("1");
                }else {
                    Long id = Long.parseLong(rs.getString("MAX(idsalida)").substring(0,rs.getString("MAX(idsalida)").length()));
                    id++;
                    txt_salida.setText("" + String.format("%01d", id));
            }
                
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Inventario_EntradaMercancia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

la segunda ya tiene la insersion a la tabla "salidamercancia" y "detallesalidamercancia", cabe aclarar que las primeras 7 columnas de la tabla "detallesalidamercancia" en la interfaz estan en un jtable.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void btn_crearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        Connection con = null; //Conexion a la base de datos.
        
         try{
            con = getConection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO salidamercancia ( fcontabilizacionsalida, fdocumentosalida, comentariossalida) "
                    + "VALUES (?,?,?)");
            SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); // para convertir el formato a la fecha deseada.
            ps.setString(1, formato.format(Dtd_fcon.getDate()));
            ps.setString(2, formato.format(Dtd_fdoc.getDate()));
            ps.setString(3, txt_comentarios.getText());
           
            int res = ps.executeUpdate();

            if(res > 0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Salida Contabilizada");
                idsalida();
                limpiar();
            }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al crear la Salida");
                idsalida();
                limpiar();
            } 
           

        } catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println(ex);
        } 
                   
       try{
            String cadena;
            int entero;
            cadena = txt_salida.getText();
            entero = Integer.parseInt(cadena);
            entero = entero -1;
            cadena = Integer.toString(entero);
            text_salida.setText(cadena);
            
            con = getConection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO detallesalidamercancia(iddetallesalida) VALUES (?)");
            
            ps.setString(1, text_salida.getText());
           
            int res = ps.executeUpdate();
    if(res > 0){          
            }else{                                 
            }
            
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        
        if(tbl_datos.getRowCount()>0){  //Cooregir el if dentro del try.
            for (int i=0; i<tbl_datos.getRowCount();i++){
                try{
                    con = getConection();
                    ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO detallesalidamercancia(idmaterialsalida, nombrematerialsalida, "
                    + "codbarrassalida, cantidadsalida, almacensalida, preciocomprasalida, totalsalida) "
                            + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                    
                    ps.setInt(1, (int) tbl_datos.getValueAt(i, 0));
                    ps.setString(2, tbl_datos.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
                    ps.setString(3, tbl_datos.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
                    ps.setInt(4, (int) tbl_datos.getValueAt(i, 3));
                    ps.setInt(5, (int) tbl_datos.getValueAt(i, 4));
                    ps.setDouble(6, (double) tbl_datos.getValueAt(i, 5));
                    ps.setInt(7, (int) tbl_datos.getValueAt(i, 6));
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    con.close();
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    Logger.getLogger(Inventario_SalidaMercancia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,ex);
                }
            }
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"");
        }
    }
```

Cuando contabilizo el documento con todos los datos digitados, solo guarda la parte que va en a tabla "salidamercancia" pero ningun dato en la tabla "detallesalidamercancia" y si los campos de la tabla "detallesalidamercancia" les quito el NOT NULL me graba todos los datos a excepcion de la columna "iddetallesalida" y si solo dejo la columna "iddetallesalida" con la propiedad NOT NULL solo me graba el dato en esta, en las demas solo guarda el NULL.

este es el error que se presenta.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'idmaterialsalida' doesn't have a default value
jul 11, 2021 7:08:41 PM Vista.Inventario_SalidaMercancia btn_crearActionPerformed
GRAVE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Vista.Inventario_SalidaMercancia.btn_crearActionPerformed(Inventario_SalidaMercancia.java:309)
    at Vista.Inventario_SalidaMercancia.access$100(Inventario_SalidaMercancia.java:24)
    at Vista.Inventario_SalidaMercancia$2.actionPerformed(Inventario_SalidaMercancia.java:81)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
```

les agradezco la ayuda que me puedan ofrecer.

Comment: Field 'idmaterialsalida' doesn't have a default value. Adiciona un valor por defecto, ya que este campo no acepta NULL.

Comment: Perdon la ignorancia, pero como le adiciono un valor por defecto?, por que al momento de insertar los datos, ingreso todas las columnas

Comment: Al parecer el valor que intentas recoger aquí: **`tbl_datos.getValueAt(i, 0)`** es `null`. Pon un punto de depuración en esa línea y verifica el valor.

Comment: si el código esta en un jinternalframeform como hago la depuración?